# Express and mongodb article

Tags: node.js, express

im a beginner to Node.js and lately ive tried to analyse the code from:http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb. But im stucked. I really don't understand how is this  code works:
    articleProvider.**findAll(function(error, docs){
      res.send(docs);
    });**

This method calls the findAll function that looks like this:
    var articleCounter = 1;
    ArticleProvider = function(){};
    ArticleProvider.prototype.dummyData = [];

```
ArticleProvider.prototype.findAll = **function(callback) {
 callback( null, this.dummyData )
};**
```

How can a method findAll to be called with a function callback that isnt even declared?! Thanks for yor help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following snippet:

```
ArticleProvider.prototype.findAll = function(callback)
...
```

is declaring `ArticleProvider.findAll` to be a function that itself takes as argument, a function named `callback`. When you invoke `ArticleProvider.findall(foo)`, the function `foo` is invoked with two arguments: `null` as the first argument, and `ArticleProvider.dummyData` as the second argument.

It may be best to get started with a good Javascript book, such as the Crockford book. Good luck.

[EDIT]

I see the suggestion to use Mongoose in one of the responses below, but after having used it, I now much prefer Guillermo Rauch's [Monk](https://github.com/LearnBoost/monk). Its much simpler than Mongoose and it lets you work without a schema. For those instances where you just want a simple layer atop MongoDB, Monk did the trick for me.

Comment: Nice to know about Monk. Seems like a very good solution for quick DB jobs in Node.

Answer (score 1):

Ram did a nice job explaining but I'd add if you are new you might want to take a look at "mongoose" rather than directly working with mongodb. Most new devs find it a little easier and because its widely used (not that mongodb directly isn't but..) you might find it easier to locate samples. here is a quick sample using [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/).

```
// require your model
var Product = require('../models/product.js');

// example getting a product by id using mongoose.
app.get('/product/:id, function (req, res) {
      Product.findOne({ _id: id }, function (err, product) {
        if(err) 
           console.log(err + '');
        else
           res.render('product, { title: 'Your Title', model: product });
     });
});
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

> How can a method findAll to be called with a function 
>   callback that isnt even declared?!

When you call

```
articleProvider.findAll(function(error, docs){ res.send(docs); });
```

you are declaring the function inline, and then passing it as an argument to find all. The "function(error, docs){ res.send(docs); }" is where you are declaring the function and passing it as a parameter.

As Ram indicated, you could have declared the function first (call it foo) and then pass it as a parameter:

```
var foo = function(error, docs){ res.send(docs); }
articleProvider.findAll(foo);
```

Notice that in either case you are passing **the function** as a parameter, not the result of executing the function.